# WordPress Condition if user is logged remove

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this in WordPress

```
<a data-user="<?php echo $place->post_author; ?>" href="#" class="print-no contact-owner-link <?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { echo 'contact-owner'; }else { echo 'contact-owner';} ?>">
        <?php _e("CONTACT OWNER", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
    </a>
```

But i want remove this condition, i want if user is or not logged can contact with owner..

Comment: The IF statement is the same in either case... ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? Just remove the conditional if you want both logged-in and logged-out users to be able to use the contact feature:

```
<a data-user="<?php echo $place->post_author; ?>" 
    href="#" class="print-no contact-owner-link contact-owner">
    <?php _e("CONTACT OWNER", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: It is not working, chekc in "CONTACTAR CON EL PROPIETARIO" IN http://www.tunsys.com/cra22/casa-rural/ejemplo-de-casa-rural/...

Thanks!

Comment: yes but not opening contact form... and when click in it must opening one contact form

Comment: sorry, i don´t understand, now the link is <a data-user="<?php echo $place->post_author; ?>" href="#" class="print-no contact-owner-link contact-owner">
            <?php _e("CONTACT OWNER", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
        </a>

Comment: `href="#"` is where you want to insert the link to the page, like any other link element